# How to force my ros package not using some ROS-provided libs?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, ros, catkin

Let say I created ros package `my_package` that depends on library (or package)`ext_package` version 1. I already installed `ext_package` as stand-alone on my machine and everything worked fine so far...

Now, I created another `new_package` but needs to use `ext_package` provided by ros to read data from topic; need to use bridge. However ROS only provides `ext_package` V2, which is not compatible with V1. Am getting compilation issues.

So I would have to rewrite completely `my_package` to accomodate V2.... which would be amazingly tedious.

Thus the question: how to edit `CMake` file such that `my_package` uses standalone `ext_package` located at `~/PathToLib/ext_package/build`?

I already tried something like,

```
unset(EXT_PACKAGE_CONFIG_PATH CACHE)
 unset(EXT_PACKAGE_DIR CACHE)

 message(STATUS  "...initial CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:")
 message(STATUS ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})

 set(TMP_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
 set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/${usrname}/soft/lib/ext_package/build/installed")

 message(STATUS  "... corrected CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH")
 message(STATUS ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})

  SET (EXT_PACKAGE_ROOT "/home/${usrname}/soft/lib/ext_package/build/installed")
  SET (EXT_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/${usrname}/soft/lib/ext_package/build/installed/include")
  SET (EXT_PACKAGE_LIBRARY_DIR "/home/${usrname}/soft/lib/ext_package/build/installed/lib")
find_package(ext_package REQUIRED)
```

... but without success. Any idea please?

Comment: It depends on how `ext_package` is designed. Can you show the content of the package, specially how the library is searched?

Comment: @wasthishelpful Yes, the `ext_package` is ViSP. The version am using is 2.10 http://visp-doc.inria.fr/doxygen/visp-2.10.0/. The ros package is `ros-catkin-visp`.

Comment: @wasthishelpful Here is a direct link to the source http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/latestfile/475/ViSP-2.10.0.tar.gz